# Remove Signature from Lotus Notes Email - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I am using some code to forward an email to an address that is selected from a worksheet. I have a signature in Lotus Notes but I don't want that signature to be there when I'm forwarding the email, but since this code uses NotesUIWorkspace it automatically pulls my signature through.

```
Public Sub Forward_Email(findSubjectLike As String, forwardToEmailAddresses As String)

    Dim NSession As Object
    Dim NMailDb As Object
    Dim NViewObj As Variant
    Dim NInboxView As Object
    Dim NDocument As Object
    Dim NUIWorkspace As Object
    Dim NUIDocument As Object
    Dim NFwdUIDocument As Object
    
    
    Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set NMailDb = NSession.CurrentDatabase
    Set NUIWorkspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

   For Each NViewObj In NMailDb.Views
        If NViewObj.IsFolder And NViewObj.Name = "($Inbox)" Then
            Set NInboxView = NViewObj
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

   
    Set NDocument = Find_Document(NInboxView, findSubjectLike)
    
    If Not NDocument Is Nothing Then
   

       
        Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.EditDocument(False, NDocument)
        
        NUIDocument.Forward
       
   
       
        Set NFwdUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
        Sleep 200
       
       
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "To"
        Sleep 200
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText forwardToEmailAddresses
       
        
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "Body"
        NFwdUIDocument.Import "HTML File", "HTML FILE DIRECTORY"
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText vbLf
        
       
        NFwdUIDocument.Send
        NFwdUIDocument.Close

       
        Do
            Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
            Sleep 200
            DoEvents
        Loop While NUIDocument Is Nothing
        NUIDocument.Close
       
    Else
   
        MsgBox vbCrLf & findSubjectLike & vbCrLf & "not found in Inbox"

    End If
   
    Set NUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NFwdUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set NMailDb = Nothing
    Set NUIWorkspace = Nothing
    Set NSession = Nothing
   
End Sub

Private Function Find_Document(NView As Object, findSubjectLike As String) As Object

    Dim NThisDoc As Object
    Dim thisSubject As String
   
    Set Find_Document = Nothing
   
    Set NThisDoc = NView.GetFirstDocument
    While Not NThisDoc Is Nothing And Find_Document Is Nothing
        thisSubject = NThisDoc.GetItemValue("Subject")(0)
        If LCase(thisSubject) = LCase(findSubjectLike) Then Set Find_Document = NThisDoc
        Set NThisDoc = NView.GetNextDocument(NThisDoc)
    Wend

End Function
```

I have a default signature pulled in with the 'Body' as a HTML file therefore I don't need my own signature as it doesn't match the type of files being forwarded. Any suggestions of how I can remove my signature without having to turn it off before using this macro?

Comment: My idea for you is to open e'mail in edit mode -> copy it, set to forward and then replace body of forwarded e'mail to delete your signature.

Comment: Why are you doing this with NotesUIDocument instead of with NotesDocument, using the NotesRichTextItem class and regular file i/o instead of the Import method to insert the contents of your file? Is the Import method translating HTML into native Notes formatting for you? It's been a long time... In fact, I don't ever actually recall using the Import method in code.